# Print data from list with condition

Tags: c, list

I need to make a function that only prints data for a certain month and year (see `case 2` and `void printList(LIST*pFirst, int pm, int py)`), but it seems I'm doing something wrong, as the whole program crashes:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#define MAX_LENGTH 80
#define LOOPS 1
struct delivery
{
    int num;
    char name[20];
    char code[8];
    char info[80];
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
    int amount;
};
typedef struct delivery BODY;
struct List{
    BODY body;
    struct List*pNext;
};
typedef struct List LIST;
int enterBody(BODY*ps);
void printBody(BODY s);
void printList(LIST*pFirst, int pm, int py);
LIST*insertBegin(LIST*pFirst, BODY newBody);

int main()
{
    FILE*pOut = NULL, *pIn = NULL;
    char Fname[] = "List_bin.dat";
    BODY newbody;
    LIST*pFirst = NULL, *p;
    int res, i, mode, pm, py;
    char sfn[20], gr[20];
    int newgr, fn;
    BODY delivery;
    char*menu[] = { "MENU:",
        "1 - Enter info for new delivery ",
        "2 - Print info for deliveries for an entered month ",
    };
    do
    {
        system("cls");
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            printf("\n%s\n", menu[i]);
        do
        {
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("\nChoose operation (1-2): ");
            res = scanf("%d", &mode);
        } while (res != 1);
        switch (mode)
        {
        case 1:
            for (i = 0; i < LOOPS; i++)
            {
                res = enterBody(&delivery);
                if (res != 1)
                {
                    printf("Error in initialization %d\n", res);
                    break;
                }
                p = insertBegin(pFirst, delivery);
                if (p == NULL)
                {
                    printf("Not enough memory! ");
                    break;
                }
                pFirst = p;
            }
            system("pause");
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("\nEnter month: ");
            scanf("%19s", pm);
            printf("\nEnter year: ");
            scanf("%19s", py);
            if (pFirst != NULL)
            {
                printList(pFirst, pm, py);
            }
            else printf("\nEmpty list!\n");
            system("pause");
            break;

        default:
            printf("\nIncorrect operation!\n");
            system("pause");
        }
    } while (mode != 11);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int enterBody(BODY*ps)
{
    if (ps == NULL) return 0;
    memset(ps, 0, sizeof(BODY));
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nEnter delivery number: ");
    scanf("%d", &(ps->num));
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nEnter name of product: ");
    gets(ps->name);
    printf("\nEnter provider code: ");
    gets(ps->code);
    printf("\nEnter provider's company, address and phone number: ");
    gets(ps->info);
    printf("\nEnter date: ");
    scanf("%d", &(ps->day));
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nEnter month: ");
    scanf("%d", &(ps->month));
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nEnter year: ");
    scanf("%d", &(ps->year));
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nEnter amount delivered: ");
    scanf("%d", &(ps->amount));
    fflush(stdin);
    return 1;
}

void printBody(BODY s)
{
    printf("\nNumber: %d\tName: %s\tCode: %s\tInfo: %s\nDate: %d-%d-%d\tAmount: %d",
        s.num, s.name, s.code, s.info, s.day, s.month, s.year, s.amount);;
}

void printList(LIST*pFirst, int pm, int py)
{
    LIST*p = NULL;

        if(strcmp(p->body.month, pm) == 0)
        p = pFirst;
        while (p != NULL)
        {
            printBody(p->body);
            p = p->pNext;
        }
        printf("\n");
}

LIST*insertBegin(LIST*pFirst, BODY newBody)
{
    LIST*p;
    p = (LIST*)malloc(sizeof(LIST));
    if (p == NULL)
    {
        printf("Not enough memory\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        p->body = newBody;
        p->pNext = pFirst;
        pFirst = p;
        return p;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd bet the problem is caused by linked lists.

Comment: In `scanf("%19s", pm);` you are passing an uninitialised `int` instead of a string addreses, hence the crash. Ditto with the following `scanf("%19s", py);`. Perhaps you mean `%d` format. Also you must check the return value from `scanf`.

Comment: Don't do `fflush(stdin)`, it's technically *undefined behavior*. If you want portable code you should not do that.

Comment: Is this **really** the minimal example necessary to replicate the error? couldn't you make a shorter demo that just uses some hard-coded dates? Then we'd know it's not something with the way you enter dates, and we'd also know which dates fail, and your code would be much shorter.

Comment: As for your problem, learn how to use a debugger. If you run a debug-build of your program in a debugger, the debugger will stop at the location the crash happens, and let you examine the variables at that location plus also let you examine the function call stack. If the location is not in your code, you walk up the function call stack until you are at your code, then examine variables to help you understand why the crash might have happened. At the very least, please edit your question to show where the crash happens in *your* code.

Comment: Also "it crashes" is not a problem description. Use a debugging tool to find out where it crashes

Answer (score 0):

You only need 2 small changes to make the program not crash for case 2. You are scanning the wrong type for a digit, you should use `%d` and a pointer to an int. And when printing the list, you need to start from the beginning.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#define MAX_LENGTH 80
#define LOOPS 1
struct delivery
{
    int num;
    char name[20];
    char code[8];
    char info[80];
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
    int amount;
};
typedef struct delivery BODY;
struct List{
    BODY body;
    struct List*pNext;
};
typedef struct List LIST;
int enterBody(BODY*ps);
void printBody(BODY s);
void printList(LIST*pFirst, int pm, int py);
LIST*insertBegin(LIST*pFirst, BODY newBody);

int main()
{
    FILE*pOut = NULL, *pIn = NULL;
    char Fname[] = "List_bin.dat";
    BODY newbody;
    LIST*pFirst = NULL, *p;
    int res, i, mode, pm, py;
    char sfn[20], gr[20];
    int newgr, fn;
    BODY delivery;
    char*menu[] = { "MENU:",
                    "1 - Enter info for new delivery ",
                    "2 - Print info for deliveries for an entered month ",
    };
    do
    {
        system("cls");
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            printf("\n%s\n", menu[i]);
        do
        {
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("\nChoose operation (1-2): ");
            res = scanf("%d", &mode);
        } while (res != 1);
        switch (mode)
        {
            case 1:
                for (i = 0; i < LOOPS; i++)
                {
                    res = enterBody(&delivery);
                    if (res != 1)
                    {
                        printf("Error in initialization %d\n", res);
                        break;
                    }
                    p = insertBegin(pFirst, delivery);
                    if (p == NULL)
                    {
                        printf("Not enough memory! ");
                        break;
                    }
                    pFirst = p;
                }
                system("pause");
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("\nEnter month: ");
                scanf("%d", &pm);
                printf("\nEnter year: ");
                scanf("%d", &py);
                if (pFirst != NULL)
                {
                    printList(pFirst, pm, py);
                }
                else printf("\nEmpty list!\n");
                system("pause");
                break;

            default:
                printf("\nIncorrect operation!\n");
                system("pause");
        }
    } while (mode != 11);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int enterBody(BODY*ps)
{
    if (ps == NULL) return 0;
    memset(ps, 0, sizeof(BODY));
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nEnter delivery number: ");
    scanf("%d", &(ps->num));
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nEnter name of product: ");
    gets(ps->name);
    printf("\nEnter provider code: ");
    gets(ps->code);
    printf("\nEnter provider's company, address and phone number: ");
    gets(ps->info);
    printf("\nEnter date: ");
    scanf("%d", &(ps->day));
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nEnter month: ");
    scanf("%d", &(ps->month));
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nEnter year: ");
    scanf("%d", &(ps->year));
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nEnter amount delivered: ");
    scanf("%d", &(ps->amount));
    fflush(stdin);
    return 1;
}

void printBody(BODY s)
{
    printf("\nNumber: %d\tName: %s\tCode: %s\tInfo: %s\nDate: %d-%d-%d\tAmount: %d",
           s.num, s.name, s.code, s.info, s.day, s.month, s.year, s.amount);;
}

void printList(LIST*pFirst, int pm, int py)
{
    LIST*p = NULL;

    p = pFirst;
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        printBody(p->body);
        p = p->pNext;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

LIST*insertBegin(LIST*pFirst, BODY newBody)
{
    LIST*p;
    p = (LIST*)malloc(sizeof(LIST));
    if (p == NULL)
    {
        printf("Not enough memory\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        p->body = newBody;
        p->pNext = pFirst;
        pFirst = p;
        return p;
    }
}
```

Test

```
MENU:

1 - Enter info for new delivery 

2 - Print info for deliveries for an entered month 

Choose operation (1-2): 1

Enter delivery number: 2

Enter name of product: 
Enter provider code: 2

Enter provider's company, address and phone number: 2

Enter date: 2

Enter month: 2

Enter year: 2

Enter amount delivered: 2
sh: 1: pause: not found
sh: 1: cls: not found

MENU:

1 - Enter info for new delivery 

2 - Print info for deliveries for an entered month 

Choose operation (1-2): 2

Enter month: 2

Enter year: 2

Number: 2   Name:   Code: 2 Info: 2
Date: 2-2-2 Amount: 2
```

Comment: Thanks, but it now prints everything, rather than just for the specified month and year.